# How to save a variable/text to use later in Cypress test?

Tags: javascript, cypress

The cypress docs(https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases.html#Elements) are pretty unclear on how alias and variables can be used to store information during a test.

I'm trying to store the text of a div on one page to use later, for example:

```
// let vpcName;
it('Store current name to use later', () => {
  // save name for later use - doesn't work
  // cy.get('#value').then(elem => {
  //   vpcName = Cypress.$(elem).text;
  // });

  // using alias - also doesn't work
  cy.get('#value')
    .invoke('text')
    .as('vpcName');
});
  
it('Use previous value to return to correct page', () => {
  cy.contains(this.vpcName).click();
});
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this:

```
cy.get('button').then(($btn) => {
  const txt = $btn.text()
  // $btn is the object that the previous command yielded
})
```

Source: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases.html#Return-Values

Comment: Using $... actually does work but according to the docs the alias `.as()` command is the best practice for this. Maybe alias only works in a beforeEach context?

Comment: that could be true, as I am seeing that Cypress is evolving so we are all trying to find ways to write script which gives consistent result. My vote is to go for method which gives consistent result in your given case

Answer (score 40):

I just came across this article that explains how and why you store a variable and then use it later in the "Cypress way":

https://www.stevenhicks.me/blog/2020/02/working-with-variables-in-cypress-tests/

In respect to how it should work, here is my example which first, collects the message (the message is shown for only 3 secs then disappears). Secondly, it gets the value using the `@` sign. Lastly my code passes the stored message through to an empty function constructed to assert that the value `Portsmouth` is contained within the message.

```
it('Current Port change', () => {
  cy.get('#viewport').find('div[id=message]').then(message => {
    let wags = message;
    cy.wrap(wags).as('wags')
  });

  cy.get('@wags').then(wags => {
     expect(wags).to.contain("Portsmouth")
  });
});
```

let me know if you need further clarification

Comment: An 'it' statement is the declaration(or start) of a test. So 2 'it' statements are technically 2 tests and so it would work for 1 test and not the other.

Answer (score 1):

I've been struggling with this for few days. Here is my approach if you want to use the saved text (for example) multiple times. However it seems too long to me and I think it could be optimized. Tested on Cypress v11.2.0

```
 cy.xpath("//tbody/tr[2]/td[2]").then(($text) => {
    let txt = $text.text()

    //expect(txt).to.eq('SomeText')
    cy.wrap(txt).as('txt')
  })

  
   cy.get('@txt').then(txt => {
        //expect(txt).to.contain("SomeText")
        cy.xpath("xpath of search field").type(txt)
     })
```

Comment: Ok, the solution works (kinda). But what if I want to use 2 saved variables in one xpath? This thing is bothering me since a while..

Answer (score 0):

I had to resort to

- [writeFile](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/writefile.html#Syntax)
- [readFile](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/readfile.html)

When I was trying to [save cookies from one test to another in Cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63636329/login-to-wordpress-without-ui-using-cypress)

Comment: Hey, on your comment, that could work if you add a command that would automatically read the saved cookies. That might be the way to do it. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution which doesn't actually store the element to a variable but serves some of the same purpose is to wrap the `cy.get` call in a function. Such as:

```js
const btn = () => cy.get('[data-testid="reset-password-button"]')

btn().should('have.attr', 'disabled')

cy.get('[data-testid="new-password-input"]').type('someNewPW')

btn().should('not.have.attr', 'disabled')
```

This could be a good option if readability is your main goal.