# Login to WordPress using Cypress, without using the UI

Tags: javascript, wordpress, cypress

In the [Cypress-docs about logging in](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/getting-started/testing-your-app.html#Logging-in) they state that one shouldn't setup the state using the UI.

But it looks like that WordPress doesn't come with a login-possibility in the API.
And since hacker-attacks are a problem on most WordPress-sites, then I would prefer not to add it.

How do I log in to WordPress using Cypress, without using the UI?

---

**Update 2020-09-03**

In case there is no way around this, then I'm just looking for the best way to do this. Is it to implement some hidden API-login-endpoint somewhere? Or is it to disregard Brian Mann's recommendation and just use the UI anyway?

---

**Update 2020-10-02**

### The overarching questions

I dived into it myself. I figured, that I could maybe set the cookies that is placed upon login. That must be the best way to do it. So the goal was to make something like this:

1. Log in the click-clicky-way (which is frowned upon).
2. Extract the cookies that was set after step1 succeeded.
3. Set those cookies before all the tests, where the user has to be logged in.

Please note, that this may come close to being an anti-patterns that is mentioned SOOOOOO many places, when you read about Cypress. So probably don't do this, if you want to be friends with Brian Mann. But I mean... Who needs dat guy!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### 2023-06 Update: The better way

There is a better way, which can be implemented using this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76165542/1766219

So you're not depending on order of tests. Or getting false failures (because the login hasn't happened).

---

### 2020: Original answer

Here is how you do it. It took me **HOURS**, - but this works for me and it's thoroughly tested. I did swap out the variables below (obviously).

I made a bunch of Commands, to swiftly be able to log in/out, between tests.

---

#### Warning - Add to .gitignore

Remember to add `adminUserLoginCookiesFromCypress.json` to you `.gitignore` - and don't upload it to your server. If that gets in the wrong hands, then someone would be able to login as your user (by adding the cookies to their own browser).

---

#### Env

This content goes in `cypress.json` in the project root.

```
{
  "env": {
    "baseUrl": "https://s1.demo.opensourcecms.com/wordpress",
    "dashboardUrl": "https://s1.demo.opensourcecms.com/wordpress/wp-admin",
    "domain": "s1.demo.opensourcecms.com/wordpress",
    "users": {
      "admin": {
        "username": "opensourcecms",
        "email": "test@example.org",
        "pw": "opensourcecms"
      }
    }
  },
}
```

#### Commands

**Clear cookies**

For some reason, I couldn't (and can't) get `cy.clearCookies()` to work.
If I run a test that logs into WP, then it's still logged, when the test runs the second time. Even if I run `cy.clearCookies()` first thing (?!)

This manual/specific clearCookie-Command worked for me:

```
Cypress.Commands.add( "clearWordPressCookies", () => {
  cy.clearCookie( 'wordpress_a8b94154380982c3184a469b8aa525c6' );
  cy.clearCookie( 'wordpress_a8b94154380982c3184a469b8aa525c6' );
  cy.clearCookie( 'wordpress_logged_in_a8b94154380982c3184a469b8aa525c6' );
  cy.clearCookie( 'wordpress_test_cookie' );
});
```

Remember to find the actual cookie-names for your site and replace the hash. [The reason for the hash in the cookie-name is due to multisite purposes](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-cookiehash-constant/)

---

**Get cookies**

Saves the cookies to a file (in the project root).

```
Cypress.Commands.add( "getWordPressCookies", () => {
  cy.getCookies()
    .then( (cookies) => {
      cy.writeFile( 'adminUserLoginCookiesFromCypress.json', cookies );
    });
});
```

---

**Set cookies**

Sets the cookies from the saved file (from the Get cookies-function).

```
Cypress.Commands.add( "setWordPressCookies", () => {

  cy.readFile( 'adminUserLoginCookiesFromCypress.json' )
    .then( (cookies) => {
      cookies.forEach( (cookie) => {
        // cy.log( JSON.stringify( cookie ) ); // See the cookie contents
        cy.setCookie( cookie.name, cookie.value, {
          domain: Cypress.env('domain'),
          path: cookie.path,
          secure: cookie.secure,
          httpOnly: cookie.httpOnly,
          expiry: cookie.expiry
        });
      });
    });
});
```

---

**Manual login**

This has to be done the first time, to get WordPress to generate the cookies.

```
Cypress.Commands.add( "manualWordPressLogin", () => {
  cy.clearWordPressCookies();
  cy.visit( Cypress.env('dashboardUrl') );
  cy.get('#user_login').wait(200).type( Cypress.env('users').admin.username , { force: true } );
  cy.get('#user_pass').wait(200).type( Cypress.env('users').admin.pw, { force: true } );
  cy.get('#wp-submit').click();
  cy.get('h1').contains( 'Dashboard' );
});
```

---

#### Example usage

```
context( 'Login, set and prep cookies' , function () {

  it( 'Ensure no one is logged in', function() {
    cy.clearWordPressCookies();
    cy.visit( Cypress.env('dashboardUrl') );
    cy.location('pathname').should('eq', '/wp-login.php' ); // Not logged in
  });


  it( 'Logs in a admin user', function(){
    cy.manualWordPressLogin();
    cy.getWordPressCookies();
    cy.visit( Cypress.env('dashboardUrl') );
    cy.location('pathname').should( 'match', /^\/wp-admin/ );
  });  
  

  it( 'logs out the user - and logs back in using setting wp-cookies', function(){
    cy.clearWordPressCookies();
    cy.visit( Cypress.env('dashboardUrl') );
    cy.location('pathname').should( 'match', /^\/wp-login\.php/ ); // Not logged in
    cy.setWordPressCookies();
    cy.visit( Cypress.env('dashboardUrl') );
    cy.location('pathname').should( 'match', /^\/wp-admin/ ); // Is logged in
  });

});
```

Comment: This put me on the right path for sure! I actually spent hours (days really) figuring out how to set cookies when I want. Not when cypress could be bothered.
My only difference to yours is that the final step of the login command is a save cookies run then.. Otherwise thank you sir :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can log in via API without a plugin and / or custom code - see this thread [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/223757/how-to-use-wp-rest-api-to-login-user-and-get-user-data-for-android-app) on wordpress /stackexchange.

However, I think if you use [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) to manage your plugins you could mitigate your exploit concerns by adding the required plugins as require-dev.

If you are not using composer have a look at something like the [Bedrock](https://roots.io/bedrock/) project, which provides a more modern architecture to Wordpress.

Once the auth plugin is added as a dev dependency you should get the ability to do headless auth via Cypress on local / staging, while keeping production safe and secure.